# Evaluating $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 2^n} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

> Evaluate
>
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2 2^n}. $$

I have tried using the Maclaurin series of $2^{-n}$ but it further complicated the question. Moreover, I have also tried taking help from another question when the $n^2$ is in the numerator, but no significant progress so far.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: TeX tip: Do not use periods for multiplication. Here they're not even needed, but if you do need something, use `\cdot`.  Using `\displaystyle` in the title of questions is frowned upon as it can do unwanted things to the site layout. And finally the guy's name is "Maclaurin". McLaren has more to do with motor sports.

Comment: See also: [$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^22^n}$ by integration or differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2248572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Given:** $$ \text{S}= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2.2^n} $$

Consider the following Lemma,

**Lemma:**

$$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ \ln x }{x+1} \mathrm{d}x = -\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

**Proof:**

$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ \ln x }{x+1} \mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ -\ln x }{1-x}\mathrm{d}x + \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ -2\ln x }{x^2-1}\mathrm{d}x$

Also,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ -\ln x }{1-x}\mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ -\ln (1-x) }{x}\mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+...}{x}\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

and,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ \ln x }{x^2-1}\mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^1 x^{2n}.{\ln{x}} \ \mathrm{d}x $

$=- \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}}$ (Using Integration By Parts)

$= \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} {\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$

$=\dfrac{-3}{4}\zeta(2)= -\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$

$\therefore  \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ \ln x }{x+1} \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - \dfrac{\pi^2}{4} = -\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$

This completes the proof of our Lemma.

**Now,**

$ \text{S}= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2.2^n} $

$= - \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \dfrac{2^n-1}{n^2.2^n} - \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)$

$ = - \displaystyle {\ln 2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{n} \int_{0}^1 2^{-nx} \mathrm{d}x \right) + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

$ = - \displaystyle {\ln 2} \int_{0}^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \times {2^{-nx}} \right)\mathrm{d}x + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

$ =  \displaystyle {\ln 2} \int_{0}^1 \ln \left( \dfrac{2^x - 1}{2^x} \right)\mathrm{d}x + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

$ =  \displaystyle {\ln 2} \int_{0}^1 \ln (2^x - 1)\ \mathrm{d}x + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} -\dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}$

Now, substituting $(2^x - 1) = t$, we have,

$\text{S} =  {\ln 2} \times \dfrac{1}{\ln 2} \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{ \ln t }{t+1} \mathrm{d}t + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} -\dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}$

$ = -\dfrac{\pi^2}{12} + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} -\dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}$ (Using the Lemma)

$=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi^2}{12} - \dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}}$

Answer (score 10):

You series equals $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. By the [functional identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function):
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)=\zeta(2)-\log(z)\log(1-z)\tag{1}$$
that is straightforward to prove by differentiation, since:
$$ \frac{d}{dz}\operatorname{Li}_2(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}=-\frac{\log(1-z)}{z},\tag{2}$$
we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2 2^n}=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log^2 2\right)}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: What's $\operatorname{Li}_2$ ? And, isn't there any elementary solution to this?

Comment: I read about the dilogarithm function from wikipedia and now have come to understand your solution. Great work +1 :) Btw, can you also help me with a similar [summation problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207985/how-to-evaluate-displaystyle-sum-n-1-infty-left-dfrach-nn12) involving Harmonic Numbers ? Thanks.

Comment: @Hard: ok, I mistyped the functional identity, now fixed.

Comment: r.h.s. of $(2)$ should be $-\frac{\log(1-z)}z$, should not it?

Comment: @user: of course, now fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k=-\log(1-x)\tag{1}
$$
Dividing $(1)$ by $x$ and integrating yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^kk^2}
&=-\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=-\left[\vphantom{\int}\log(1-x)\log(x)\right]_0^{1/2}
-\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}\\
&=-\log(2)^2-\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log(1-x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\
&=-\frac{\log(2)^2}2-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2d}\\
&=-\frac{\log(2)^2}2+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\tag{2e}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{-\frac{\log(2)^2}2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}}\tag{2f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: divide $(1)$ by $x$ and integrate over $[0,1/2]$
$\text{(2b)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(2c)}$: substitute $x\mapsto1-x$
$\text{(2d)}$: average $\text{(2a)}$ and $\text{(2c)}$
$\text{(2e)}$: divide $(1)$ by $x$ and integrate over $[0,1]$
$\text{(2f)}$: $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$

Answer (score 3):

the taylor series of $$y=\frac{1}{x}\log(\frac{1}{1-x})$$ is
$$y=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{4}+...\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}$$
$$\int_{0}^{0.5}ydx=x+\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{3^2}+\frac{x^4}{4^2}+...\frac{x^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(.5)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^nn^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^nn^2}=\int_{0}^{0.5}\frac{1}{x}\log\frac{1}{1-x}dx$$