# Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n-1}n^2} = (\ln 2)^2$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n-1}n^2} = (\ln 2)^2$.

I've been trying to find a solution this for a while now, but I can't make any progress. The problem comes from a math competition, so there should be an elementary solution to this. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Split the sum, the first term is $ \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ and for the other term try to write it in terms of a power series

Comment: Using clark's hint, you can use [this for the 'other term'.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706647/computing-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-2n)

Comment: What confuses me is that is it $\ln{(2^2)}$ or $(\ln2)^2$?

Comment: It is perhaps better to write $\ln (2)^2$ as either $(\ln 2)^2$ or $\ln^2 (2)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056052/proof-of-dilogarithm-reflection-formula-zeta2-logx-log1-x-operatorname/1056111#1056111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the series converges absolutely we can write
$$S = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left [\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{2}{2^n n^2} \right ] = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(1/2)^n}{n^2}.$$

The first sum to the right corresponds to the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\zeta (s)$, namely
$$\zeta (s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s},$$
when $s = 2$ while the second corresponds to the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) $\text{Li}_2 (x)$, namely
$$\text{Li}_2 (x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2},$$ 
when $x = 1/2$. Thus
$$S = \zeta(2) - 2\text{Li}_2 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ).$$

Now using the (reasonably?) well-known result for the value of dilogarithm function when its argument is equal to one half, namely
$$\text{Li}_2 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) = \frac{1}{2} \zeta (2) - \frac{1}{2} \ln^2 (2),$$
we immediately see the series sums to $\ln^2 (2)$.