# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^22^n}$ by integration or differentiation

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is an infinite sum given:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^22^n}$$
It should be solved using integration, derivation or both.
I think using power series can help but I don't know how to finish the calculation. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $Li_{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{ (\ln 2)^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you! But how did you get that? @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: I copied it from here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function ... I am scribbling in my note book now ... I will get back to you when I have managed to derive it ...

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm really looking forward to the solution!

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1056111/44121

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that we have $\int_0^x t^{n-1}\,dt=\frac{x^n}{n}$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x t^{n-1}\,dt\int_0^x s^{n-1}\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^x\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-st}\,ds\,dt\\\\
&=-\int_0^{x} \frac{\log(1-sx)}{s}\,ds\\\\
&=-\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\log(1-s)}{s}\,ds\\\\
&=\text{Li}_2(x^2)
\end{align}$$

Evaluating at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\,2^n}=\text{Li}_2(1/2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\log^2(2)}$$

And we are done!

---

To evaluate $\text{Li}_2(1/2)$, we exploit the relationship

$$\text{Li}_2(1-x)=-\text{Li}_2\left(1-\frac1x\right)-\frac12\log^2(x)$$

Letting $x=1/2$ yields

$$\text{Li}_2(1/2)=-\text{Li}_2\left(-1\right)-\frac12\log^2(1/2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\log^2(2)$$

where we used

$$\begin{align}
\text{Li}_2(-1)&=-\int_0^{-1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}$$

Comment: That's a nice solution! Thanks. However I must ask about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}$. Why are we considering such a sum?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The value of that sum when $x=1/\sqrt 2$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\,2^n}$.

Comment: The value truly is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^22^n}$! Thus I have the next question. Why did you decided to take an $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$? Just because it works?

Comment: Well, yes.  We took $x=1/\sqrt 2$ in order that we would have the sum of interest.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments were really helpful. I have to ask about one more thing. How did you get $\int_0^x\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-st}\,ds\,dt$?

Comment: You're welcome again.  And good question.  We sum the geometric series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (st)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-st}$$

Comment: Thanks! And the last question - how did you integrate $\int_0^x\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-st}\,ds\,dt$?

Comment: Why does the upper limit of the integrand become squared in the last step of your initial derivation.

Comment: @Tyberius The first integral yields $$\int_0^x \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-st}\,dt\,ds=-\int_0^x \frac{\log(1-sx)}{s}\,ds=-\int_0^{x^2}\frac{\log(1-s)}{s}\,ds=\text{Li}_2(x^2)$$

Answer (score 11):

Another way to calculate it: consider
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2}.
$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ gives
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}\quad\Rightarrow\quad xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
(xf'(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Now integrating with $f(0)=0$
$$
xf'(x)=-\ln(1-x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=-\int_0^x\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\,dt.
$$
Motivation for termwise differentiation for power series is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

[My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3238446/675350) to a duplicate question says:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$$
 Integrating from 0 to t we get
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(1-x)}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t} x^{n}dx$$$$-\ln(1-t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{n}$$
Dividing by t and integrating
$$\int_{0}^{0.5}-\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}2^{n}}$$
This on calculating is $$ \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}-\dfrac{ln^2(2)}{2},$$

Comment: This answer is identical to your answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238429/evaluating-an-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n22n). If the questions are the same, this one should be flagged as a duplicate. If not, then it would be more efficient and less noisy to cite or quote (with attribution) from the other answer. The link between the answers would also serve as a link between two closely related questions. In this case, the questions *were* duplicates.

Comment: @robjohn So should I change anything ??. I posted it here because the other one was marked as duplicate. Should I remove it from here??

Comment: Even though the other question was closed, your answer there is still active and getting votes. One should be removed, but you might edit one to reference the other; you might just say something like, "[my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3238446) to a duplicate question says..."

Comment: Okay , I will link my answers